# php - Put data in .csv file

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I'm trying to put some data in a .csv file using PHP, I can put it in the file but the thing is that the double quotes are messing me. Here's the kind of text I have to put in my .csv file:

```
#2500
Pittsburgh Penguins 3 , Montreal Canadiens 5
Shots: 28 - 25
PIT PP: 1 of 3 (4 shots), Passing:65/82=79 %, Challenges:31/38=79 %
MTL PP: 0 of 3 (7 shots), Passing:66/84=78 %, Challenges:42/50=82 %
Attendance: 6839 of 18387 (PPG Paints Arena)
Ticket income: 317330 Match televised: No


Pittsburgh Penguins scoring.
                         ( G  A  Sh Hi Ga Ta PIM, +/-  Icetime Rating)
R Ryan Reaves             0  0  0  0  1  0    0    0    7.40    5
R Bryan Rust              0  0  0  0  2  0    0   -1   11.50    5
R Carl Hagelin            0  0  3  0  0  0    0   -1   14.50    6
R Patric Hörnqvist        1  0  3  6  0  0    2   -1   20.40    9
C Michael Raffl           0  0  2  2  0  1    0    0    9.00    7
C Riley Sheahan           0  0  0  2  0  1    0   -1   17.10    7
C Evgeni Malkin           1  1  3  0  0  0    0    0   16.20    7
C Sidney Crosby           0  1  3  1  0  0    0   -2   17.30    7
L Greg McKegg             0  0  3  3  2  0    2    0    8.50    6
L Tom Kuhnhackl           0  0  0  0  1  0    0   -1   11.50    5
L Jake Guentzel           1  1  4  0  0  0    2    0   20.10    8
L Conor Sheary            0  0  2  0  0  0    0   -2   17.30    6
D Jamie Oleksiak          0  0  1  1  0  1    0   -1   13.00    7
D Olli Määttä             0  1  1  1  0  0    0   -1   13.40    6
D John Carlson            0  0  1  0  0  0    0   -1   21.40    7
D Brian Dumoulin          0  0  0  1  0  3    0   -1   19.00    6
D Justin Schultz          0  0  3  0  0  0    0   -1   18.30    7
D Kris Letang             0  1  1  2  0  1    0   -1   26.20    7
                         (GA,  A, Sv , PIM, +/- Icetime Rating)
G Matthew Murray          5   0   20   0    0   59.00    4
G Tristan Jarry           0   0   0    0    0    0.00    0

Montreal Canadiens scoring.
                         ( G  A  Sh Hi Ga Ta PIM, +/-  Icetime Rating)
R Derek Dorsett           0  0  0  2  2  2    0   -1   14.00    6
R Andrew Shaw             1  0  2  1  1  1    0    1   14.10    7
R Brendan Gallagher       0  1  1  0  0  0    2    2   11.50    7
R Max Pacioretty          0  1  3  2  1  0    0    1   20.40    7
C Michael McCarron        0  0  1  1  1  0    2   -1   11.00    6
C Paul Byron              0  2  2  0  0  0    0    1   19.20    8
C Phillip Danault         1  0  2  0  0  0    0    2   14.10    7
C Jonathan Drouin         1  0  8  0  0  1    0    1   20.40    9
L Nicolas Deslauriers     0  0  2  1  0  0    2   -1   13.20    7
L Artturi Lehkonen        0  0  2  0  0  0    0    1   11.50    7
L Charles Hudon           1  1  3  0  1  0    0    2   13.30    9
L Alex Galchenyuk         1  0  3  2  1  0    0    1   20.40    8
D David Schlemko          0  0  0  0  0  0    0    1   11.50    6
D Jeff Petry              0  0  0  2  0  2    0    1   17.20    7
D Shea Weber              0  0  0  0  0  0    0    1   30.10    7
D Jordie Benn             0  1  0  1  1  1    0    1   13.10    6
D Karl Alzner             0  2  0  0  0  0    0    2   14.00    7
D Shea Theodore           0  2  1  0  0  0    0    0   26.00    9
                         (GA,  A, Sv , PIM, +/- Icetime Rating)
G Carey Price             3   0   25   0    0   60.00    7
G Antti Niemi             0   0   0    0    0    0.00    0

Three stars of the game:
1st star: Charles Hudon
2nd star: Shea Theodore
3rd star: Andrew Shaw

Notes for Pittsburgh Penguins:

Notes for Montreal Canadiens:

Other notes:


###
```

The important things here are the '#' that allows me to delimiter ma text to put in an array. Here's my code:

```
$gameChange = "###";
$i = 0;
$reportList = array();
$allReports = array();
$lineStr = null;

$reportsFile = fopen("reports.ehm", "r");
if ($reportsFile) {
    while (($line = fgets($reportsFile)) !== false) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            array_push($reportList, trim(str_replace("#","",$line)));
        }
        if (trim($line) == $gameChange) {
            array_push($reportList, $lineStr));
            array_push($allReports, $reportList);
            $reportList = array();
            $lineStr = "";
            $i = 0;
        } else {
            if ($i != 0) {
                $lineStr = $lineStr.$line;
            }
            $i += 1;
        }
    }

    fclose($reportsFile);

    $reportsFileCSV = fopen("reports.csv", "w");
    foreach ($allReports as $report) {
        fputcsv($reportsFileCSV, [
            $report[0],
            $report[1],
        ],'|');
    }
    fclose($reportsFileCSV);
} else {
    echo "ERROR!";
}
```

The logic is good it results in a decent .csv file but it looks like when I **fputcsv** it keeps the double quotes.

I have tried `str_replace('"', '', $line)` and using the trim function but no results.

Here is the result of the data in the .csv file:

```
2500|"Pittsburgh Penguins 3 , Montreal Canadiens 5
Shots: 28 - 25
PIT PP: 1 of 3 (4 shots), Passing:65/82=79 %, Challenges:31/38=79 %
MTL PP: 0 of 3 (7 shots), Passing:66/84=78 %, Challenges:42/50=82 %
Attendance: 6839 of 18387 (PPG Paints Arena)
Ticket income: 317330 Match televised: No


Pittsburgh Penguins scoring.
                         ( G  A  Sh Hi Ga Ta PIM, +/-  Icetime Rating)
R Ryan Reaves             0  0  0  0  1  0    0    0    7.40    5
R Bryan Rust              0  0  0  0  2  0    0   -1   11.50    5
R Carl Hagelin            0  0  3  0  0  0    0   -1   14.50    6
R Patric Hörnqvist        1  0  3  6  0  0    2   -1   20.40    9
C Michael Raffl           0  0  2  2  0  1    0    0    9.00    7
C Riley Sheahan           0  0  0  2  0  1    0   -1   17.10    7
C Evgeni Malkin           1  1  3  0  0  0    0    0   16.20    7
C Sidney Crosby           0  1  3  1  0  0    0   -2   17.30    7
L Greg McKegg             0  0  3  3  2  0    2    0    8.50    6
L Tom Kuhnhackl           0  0  0  0  1  0    0   -1   11.50    5
L Jake Guentzel           1  1  4  0  0  0    2    0   20.10    8
L Conor Sheary            0  0  2  0  0  0    0   -2   17.30    6
D Jamie Oleksiak          0  0  1  1  0  1    0   -1   13.00    7
D Olli Määttä             0  1  1  1  0  0    0   -1   13.40    6
D John Carlson            0  0  1  0  0  0    0   -1   21.40    7
D Brian Dumoulin          0  0  0  1  0  3    0   -1   19.00    6
D Justin Schultz          0  0  3  0  0  0    0   -1   18.30    7
D Kris Letang             0  1  1  2  0  1    0   -1   26.20    7
                         (GA,  A, Sv , PIM, +/- Icetime Rating)
G Matthew Murray          5   0   20   0    0   59.00    4
G Tristan Jarry           0   0   0    0    0    0.00    0

Montreal Canadiens scoring.
                         ( G  A  Sh Hi Ga Ta PIM, +/-  Icetime Rating)
R Derek Dorsett           0  0  0  2  2  2    0   -1   14.00    6
R Andrew Shaw             1  0  2  1  1  1    0    1   14.10    7
R Brendan Gallagher       0  1  1  0  0  0    2    2   11.50    7
R Max Pacioretty          0  1  3  2  1  0    0    1   20.40    7
C Michael McCarron        0  0  1  1  1  0    2   -1   11.00    6
C Paul Byron              0  2  2  0  0  0    0    1   19.20    8
C Phillip Danault         1  0  2  0  0  0    0    2   14.10    7
C Jonathan Drouin         1  0  8  0  0  1    0    1   20.40    9
L Nicolas Deslauriers     0  0  2  1  0  0    2   -1   13.20    7
L Artturi Lehkonen        0  0  2  0  0  0    0    1   11.50    7
L Charles Hudon           1  1  3  0  1  0    0    2   13.30    9
L Alex Galchenyuk         1  0  3  2  1  0    0    1   20.40    8
D David Schlemko          0  0  0  0  0  0    0    1   11.50    6
D Jeff Petry              0  0  0  2  0  2    0    1   17.20    7
D Shea Weber              0  0  0  0  0  0    0    1   30.10    7
D Jordie Benn             0  1  0  1  1  1    0    1   13.10    6
D Karl Alzner             0  2  0  0  0  0    0    2   14.00    7
D Shea Theodore           0  2  1  0  0  0    0    0   26.00    9
                         (GA,  A, Sv , PIM, +/- Icetime Rating)
G Carey Price             3   0   25   0    0   60.00    7
G Antti Niemi             0   0   0    0    0    0.00    0

Three stars of the game:
1st star: Charles Hudon
2nd star: Shea Theodore
3rd star: Andrew Shaw

Notes for Pittsburgh Penguins:

Notes for Montreal Canadiens:

Other notes:


"
```

It seems to put a line separator at the beginning of the string and at the end too so when I try to put it in the DB, there's no data.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: that is not valid csv content.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I use the `|` to delimiter my fields cause the comma would separate it in the middle of my string since there's a comma after Pittsburgh Penguins 3 ,

Comment: why are you trying to get rid of double quote? If you don't have your multiline cell value quoted, how do you know when it ends?